# Totally bounded and closed subset of complete metric space => compact

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces

I've read that a totally bounded and closed set $A \subseteq E$ is compact if $E$ is a complete metric space.
There was not a direct proof they only referenced a theorem of another book.
The theorem in that book states, that a complete space $E$ is compact if and only if $E$ is complete and totally bounded.
But that does not really explain why totally bounded and closed subsets of $E$ are compact or am I missing something?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: A closed subset of a complete metric space is also complete.

Comment: Thanks, complete for a subset $A\subseteq E$ means that every sequence in A converges in A, right? I'm asking because on a lot of sites and books I read it only defines what completeness means for the metric space itself.

Comment: You are correct.